# Run a batch file on a remote computer to update a git branch

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, psexec

I wrote this script:

```
ECHO hi
cd "C:\config_folder"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git" pull origin master
ECHO bye
```

I put this script on my remote server in this folder "C:\config_folder".

Now when i run this script from my local PC using this tool:

https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-PL/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

```
C:\Users\ME\Desktop\PSTools>psexec.exe -u Administrator -p 123456 \\x.x.x.x "C:\config_folder\test.bat"
```

i get the following on my screen, the script is stuck on this git pull command in an infinite loop...no idea why...what did i miss?

---

```
C:\Windows\system32>ECHO hi
hi

C:\Windows\system32>cd "C:\config_folder"

C:\config_folder>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git" pull origin master
```

---

Comment: Are you sure its running in the right folder? maybe the git pull is executed in the current directory and not in your git repo

Comment: it's running in the right folder. that's why i added: cd "C:\config_folder" in the script.

Comment: and if you are standing in the folder and execute the command in bash is it working as well?

Comment: yes. i ran the script on the remote server and it worked just fine. but remotely, when i run the script from my PC with this tool, i get this behavior, you can see the "echo" is working, so the issue is with "git pull..."

Comment: What is your url for the repo? http? git? ssh? maybe its prompting you for password

Comment: "origin" url is: "https://me@bitbucket.org/me/config.git". and i used this link to save username and password. https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/git-credential-store.html. so when i ran the script on the remote server. it didn't ask for username and password it's already cached.

Comment: but the script might be running under a different user

Comment: can you please explain? I'm connecting to the remote server under user:Administrator. so the script should run under this user. but if i already cached the username/password in .git-credentials file, where Administrator user has access to this file, why would that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it, i needed to connect to the remote server with my user, not Admin, now the issue is solved. Thanks